# set PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--name" "PySparkShell" "pyspark-shell" && jupyter notebook

Tags: pyspark

I'm looking to install PySpark on my Windows 10 machine and have been unable to correctly specify the PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS argument.

This is the error I'm seeing when I run the "pyspark" command from gitbash:

```
$ pyspark
set PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--name" "PySparkShell" "pyspark-shell" && jupyter notebook
```

I've uninstalled all versions of Java, except version 8. Within my .bashrc file, my path is currently specified as:

```
export JAVA_HOME="C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre1.8.0_261"
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[*] pyspark-shell"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export SPARK_HOME="C:/spark/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7"
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

And JAVA_HOME is specified within my env variables and set in Path as well.

I would really appreciate any additional troubleshooting techniques!

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run from windows command prompt , having issues with gitbash